# Elementary OS Google Pinyin not showing up Japanese choice

Tags: keyboard, language, ime, elementaryos, japanese

I installed the Google Pinyin bundle altogether to the other necessary packages. Then, configured it correctly by choosing fcitx through the im-config.

After rebooting the system the keyboard symbol shows up on wingpanel, so I chose Japanese as one of the methods. So far so good.

The thing is, once I use the hot-key combination that was supposed to display the option for the Japanese typing  the only option I get is Keyboard - English (US)...[image]

How do I correct?

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling ibus and everything about the fcitx that I had earlier installed and reinstalling the fcitx and company there was no solution still. There was no Mozc option so I added it later as an input method.

But it still didn't work. So, following the tip from [an online spot](https://moritzmolch.com/1453) I atyped the following:

sudo apt-get install ibus-mozc

And tcha-rá! It works fine!